# metal compute function limitations

Tags: gpgpu, metal

I experienced that `MTLBuffer`s with computionally intensive shader functions tend to stop calculating before all `threadgroups` are done. When I use a `MTLComputePipelineState` and `MTLComputeCommandEncoder` to blur an image with very large blur radii the resulting image half way processed and one can actually see half finished `threadgroups`. I did not narrow it down to the exact amount of blur radius, but 16 pixels works fine, 32 is already too much and not even half the groups are computed.

So are there any limitations on how long a shader function call should take to finish or anything like that? I just finished most of the documentation about how to use the Metal framework and I cannot recall stumbling upon any such statements.

### EDIT

Since in my case the problem was not a simple timeout but some internal error I'm going to add some code.

The most expensive part of is the block-matching algorithm that finds matching blocks in two images (i.e consecutive frames in a movie)

```
//Exhaustive Search Block-matching algorithm
kernel void naiveMotion(
    texture2d<float,access::read>   inputImage1   [[ texture(0) ]],
    texture2d<float,access::read>   inputImage2   [[ texture(1) ]],
    texture2d<float,access::write>  outputImage  [[ texture(2) ]],
uint2 gid                                    [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]
)
{
    //area to search for matches
    float searchSize = 10.0;
    int searchRadius = searchSize/2;

    //window size to search in
    int kernelSize = 6;
    int kernelRadius = kernelSize/2;

    //this will store the motion direction
    float2 vector = float2(0.0,0.0);
    float2 maxVector = float2(searchSize,searchSize/2);
    float maxVectorLength = length(maxVector);

    //maximum error caused by noise
    float error = kernelSize*kernelSize*(10.0/255.0);


    for (int y = -searchRadius; y < searchRadius; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < searchSize; ++x)
        {
            float diff = 0;
        
            for (int b = - kernelRadius; b < kernelRadius; ++b)
            {
                for (int a = - kernelRadius; a < kernelRadius; ++a)
                {
                    uint2 textureIndex(gid.x + x + a, gid.y + y + b);
                    float4 targetColor = inputImage2.read(textureIndex).rgba;
                    float4 referenceColor = inputImage1.read(gid).rgba;
                    float targetGray = 0.299*targetColor.r + 0.587*targetColor.g + 0.114*targetColor.b;
                    float referenceGray = 0.299*referenceColor.r + 0.587*referenceColor.g + 0.114*referenceColor.b;
                    diff = diff + abs(targetGray - referenceGray);
                }
            }
        
            if ( error > diff )
            {
                error = diff;
                //vertical motion is rather irrelevant but negative values can't be stored so just take the absolute value
                vector = float2(x, abs(y));
            }
        }
    }

    float intensity = length(vector)/maxVectorLength;
    outputImage.write(float4(normalize(vector), intensity, 1),gid);
}
```

I am using that shader on a 960x540px image. With a `searchSize` of 9 and `kernelSize` of 8 the shader runs over the whole image. Changing the searchSize to 10 and the shader will stop early with an error code 1.

Comment: Yes, there is a defined timeout, if you print out the error from the command buffer handler you will get code 2. If you have a large kernel why don't you use integral images? https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/07/15/an-investigation-of-fast-real-time-gpu-based-image-blur-algorithms

Comment: Thanks so much! I figured that I read the wrong Error object. The one I created the pipelineState with instead of the buffer's error. No wonder that didn't tell me anything. Now the buffer.error tells me that the error code is 1 (internal error) and userInfo says "IOAcceleratorFamily returned error code 5" which I can't find any useful information about. Still it's good to know there also is a time limitation. Also I'll have another look at the link you provided and how Integral Images work - I didn't quite get the idea on the first look. Thank you for pointing these out!

Comment: You can see them here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLCommandBuffer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MTLCommandBufferError code 1 is a compilation error, did you use something like arrays with dynamic size in the shader? If you post your code I can take a look.

Comment: I updated my post with my shader code if you like to look at it. But no, I don't use anything but textures as you can in the code. There are no dynamic arrays involved. Isn't code 1 mapped to `CommandBufferError.Internal` which is "An internal error that doesn't fit into the other categories. The actual low level error code is encoded in the local description." The low level error is "IOAcceleratorFamily returned error code 5" like I mentioned earlier which I can't find anything useful about.

Comment: I also had another look at integral images. They'd be perfect for block-matching, but that'll only be the next step after the shader works properly.

Comment: First of all I suggest that you split that kernel in multiple passes, one for each disparity (x,y). That is way too much work for a single pass and it's not how GPUs best work. The write statement looks suspicious, try to comment it out and see if you still get the error. If yes, simplify your shader and compile for each line you add, you should be able to find what the problem is.

Comment: So did you ever figure this out?  I noticed this question and ran your code, and it seems to work very well for me.  It outputs an image with lots of pink, green, and some black.

Comment: I didn't figure out what exactly those error codes meant, but in the end simplifying or dividing the work solved the problem. I ran this code on an iPad Mini 2 which would send the error after almost finishing half of the work. My guess is that the hardware you ran the code on might be more powerful and therefor finishes without error. I would have liked to run this code again with new hardware but the project was written in swift 1.2 and it took me already over an hour to resolve errors that came with swift 3 and it's still not running. I'll copy the shader into a new project on the weekend.